# awk line break with printf

Tags: shell, awk, db2

I have a simple shell script, shown below, and I want to put a line break after each line returned by it.

```
#!/bin/bash
vcount=`db2 connect to db_lexus > /dev/null; db2 list tablespaces | grep -i "Tablespace ID" | wc -l`
db2pd -d db_lexus -tablespaces | grep -i "Tablespace Statistics" -A $vcount | awk '{printf ($2 $7)}'
```

The output is:

```
Statistics:IdFreePgs0537610230083224460850d
```

and I want the output to be something like that:

```
Statistics:
Id FreePgs
0 5376
1 0
2 3008
3 224
4 608
5 0
```

Is that possible to do with shell scripting?

Comment: All things are possible with shell scripting. Try `import antigravity` in python some time.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem can be reduced to the following:

```
$ cat infile
11 12
21 22
$ awk '{ printf ($1 $2) }' infile
11122122
```

`printf` is for *formatted printing*. I'm not even sure if the behaviour of above usage is defined, but it's not how it's meant to be done. Consider:

```
$ awk '{ printf ("%d %d\n", $1, $2) }' infile
11 12
21 22
```

`"%d %d\n"` is an expression that describes how to format the output: "a decimal integer, a space, a decimal integer and a newline", followed by the numbers that go where the `%d` are. `printf` is very flexible, see the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printf) for what it can do.

In this case, we don't really need the power of `printf`, we can just use `print`:

```
$ awk '{ print $1, $2 }' infile
11 12
21 22
```

This prints the first and second field, separated by a space<sup>1</sup> – and `print` *does* add a newline without us telling it to.

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, "separated by the value of the output field separator `OFS`", which defaults to a space and is printed wherever we use `,` between two arguments. Forgetting the comma is a popular mistake that leads to no space between the record fields.

Comment: Benjamin, thank you for your explanation about the correct use of awk and print command. both you and e0k help me. It was just a simple change in my script that makes retrieve exactly I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want to print columns 2 and 7 of whatever is passed to AWK.  Try changing your AWK command to

```
    awk '{print $2, $7}'
```

This will also add a line break at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much. As I said before, I don't have much experience with Shell Scripting. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you are asking about how to do something in a shell script, but it would certainly be a LOT easier to get this from the database using SQL:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DB2DBDFT=db_lexus

db2 "select tbsp_id, tbsp_free_pages \
       from table(mon_get_tablespace('',-2)) as T \
   order by tbsp_id"
```

Comment: Ian, you are totally right. I could do running a simple query on mon_get_tablespace table function and get the tbspid and tbsp_free_pages but as I never was good writing shell scripts I needed to try improve my knowledges in shell scripting. Thank you.